# Everything works weell unless it gives me a true result and nothing changes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im trying to write a password changing script. Everything goes right. Ecxept that. It tells me it is successful but nothing changes. Nothing changes in the encrypted code in my mysql and also when i try to login, i cant use the new password but only the old password. Here is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('inc/functions.inc.php');
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    die(header("Location: settings.php"));
}
if (isset($_SESSION['updatePasswordError'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['updatePasswordError']);
}
$_SESSION['updatePasswordError'] = array();

if (isset($_SESSION['updatePasswordSuccess'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['updatePasswordSuccess']);
}
$_SESSION['updatePasswordSuccess'] = array();

if (strlen($_POST['newpassword'])  < 8) {
    $_SESSION['updatePasswordError'][] = "New Password must be at least 8 characters";
}
else if ($_POST['newpassword'] != $_POST['confirmnewpassword']) {
    $_SESSION['updatePasswordError'][] = "Passwords don’t match";
}

$mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    error_log("Cannot connect to MySQL: " .
              $mysqli->connect_error);
    return false;
}
$incomingOldPassword = $mysqli->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['currentpassword']));
$query = "SELECT * from Customer WHERE id = '{$user->id}'";
if (!$result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $_SESSION['updatePasswordError'][] = "Select Error. Try Again";
    error_log("Cannot retrieve account for {$user}");
    return false;
}
// Will be only one row, so no while() loop needed
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$dbPassword = $row['password'];
if (crypt($incomingOldPassword,$dbPassword) != $dbPassword) {
    $_SESSION['updatePasswordError'][] = "Old Password Incorrect";
}

if (count($_SESSION['updatePasswordError']) > 0) {
    die(header("Location: settings.php"));
} else {
    $cryptednewPassword = crypt($_POST['newpassword']);
    $newPassword = $mysqli->real_escape_string($cryptednewPassword);
    $result = "$updatePassword($newPassword)";
    if ($result) {
        $_SESSION['updatePasswordSuccess'] [] = "Successfully Updated";
        die(header("Location: settings.php"));
    } else {
        die(header("Location: settings.php"));
    }
}


function updatePassword($newPassword) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
    $query = "UPDATE customer SET password = ? WHERE id = $user->id";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $newPassword);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $mysqli->close();
    return $result;
}
?>
```

If i try using an incorrect password, non matching password or less than 8 characters, i get an error. But everything seems alright apart from that

Comment: There's no need to unset a variable right before you assign a new value to it.

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode parameters. That should only be used when displaying user-generated data on web pages, to prevent XSS exploits.

Comment: Where do you set `$user`?

Comment: You should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for password encryption, not `crypt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the `updatePassword()` function. This line:

```
$result = "$updatePassword($newPassword)";
```

doesn't call a function. It just creates a string containing the values of the variables `$updatePassword` and `$newPassword`. Since `$updatePassword` doesn't exist, it's equivalent to writing:

```
$result = "($newPassword)";
```

You should also have gotten a warning message about the undefined variable.

The way to call the function is:

```
$result = updatePassword($newPassword);
```

You don't put a function call inside quotes, and you don't put `$` before the function name.

You also need to set `$user` in the main script, and pass it as an argument to the function or use `global $user;` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks. I changed that. But, still the same answer. Im trying to call a variable from an object page. is this correct $query = "UPDATE customer SET password = ? WHERE id = '{$user->id}'";

Comment: It's correct if you set `$user` properly. Aren't you getting a warning about an undefined variable?

Comment: I am not getting an error for unset variable. Ive used other variables of this in a print version too. i dont knw why its not working. Ive used user->username etc

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` enabled? There doesn't seem to be anything setting `$user`, unless it's set in `functions.inc.php`.

Comment: Even if it's set in the main script, it's not set in the scope of function. Read the last line of the answer.

Comment: I'll check for error reporting. There is a require classuser in the functions file. However, i tried putting an hidden input for the user->id in the settings file and then i uses a $_post to get it in the function inside the variable. So, i have something like $userid=$_POST['userid];

Comment: I then used where id = $userid. And im getting this error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\two\inc\update-password.inc.php:64 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\two\inc\update-password.inc.php(49): updatePassword('$1$BC5V4zBN$00f...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\two\profile-update.php(5): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\two\inc\update-password.inc.php on line 64

Comment: That means `prepare()` got an error. You need to check whether it's successful, and print `$db->error` when it fails.

Comment: It should be `$query = "UPDATE customer SET password = ? WHERE id = ?";` and then `$stmt->bind_param("si", $newPassword, $userid);`

Comment: @Layoolar You shouldn't use `real_escape_string` for parameters that are bound with `bind_param`.

Comment: Thankds. The function now looks like this function updatePassword() {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
    $cryptednewPassword = crypt($_POST['newpassword']);
    $query = "UPDATE Customer SET password = ? WHERE id = '{$user->id}'";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $cryptednewPassword);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $mysqli->close();
    return $result;
}

Comment: if (count($_SESSION['updatePasswordError']) > 0) {
        die(header("Location: settings.php"));
        } else {

 $cryptednewPassword = crypt($_POST['newpassword']);
$result = updatePassword();
if ($result) {
    $_SESSION['updatePasswordSuccess'] [] = "Successfully Updated";
    die(header("Location: settings.php"));
} else {
    die(header("Location: settings.php"));
}
        }

Comment: You still haven't set `$user` anywhere in the function. Do you understand variable scope?

Comment: Im totally confused. Im just getting successful. Dont understand anymore

Comment: Since `$user` is not set, `$user->id` is empty, so it's doing `WHERE id = ''`.

Comment: That won't report an error, but there's nothing for it to update.

Comment: Why do you insist on using variable substitution instead of `bind_param` for `$user->id`?